# Multiple Regression Extreme Values in all Covariates

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, dataset

In multiple regression:
If we have a data set with covariates having extreme values, the max value of the covariate is around 10 to 14 times the mean value of that covariate. This is occurring for all the covariates.
Is it better to remove the rows containing the extreme data for each covariate?

Comment: There is no inherent problem with this.  See our posts on [regression diagnostics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+diagnostic+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10) for information on what you *ought* to be checking in your analyses.